# My Android app is not displaying in play store search list, even if the app is in published status

Tags: google-play

I have developed an App and published the same in google play store console. Even after many days the app is not getting listed in play store while searching using App Name.

I have tried searching using the project name. Its shows my app while searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Answer for my question from Google Developer Support ... !!!!]
Please enlarge the image and the answer is there

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. It need time, interactions and downloads to scale the list.
Don't worry